# How to avoid leading whitespace being trimmed off of directive string bindings?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a custom directive that I want to use to display the value of a field and an optional suffix (expected for units and such). Note that my example is shortened to stay concise.

My template looks something like

```
<div class="my-value">{{boundValue}}{{boundSuffix}}</div>
```

For the value, I'm using a two-way binding (=) and for the suffix, I'm using a string binding (&).

It worked great when I bound `&deg` into the suffix to display a temperature, but when I tried to bind in `meters` (note, there's a leading space - I don't want it pushed up against the number) the leading space seems to get trimmed and my result ends up looking like `123meters`.

Using the chrome developer tools, I added a link function and inspected the directive's scope. By the time it reaches the link function, `boundSuffix` has already been trimmed. It seems like Angular is pulling some shenanigans on my behind the hood. Is there any way for me to avoid this trimming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use angular `filters` to solve your problem. Filters allow to format your output as currency or as UPPERCASE (for example). Try to look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters) for more info. And here is [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/qv97IwXuq8UDWZS7U6VK?p=preview)

Comment: Filters are a good alternative, and I had considered them. The directive is generic and I'm trying not to make it aware of what kind of data it's displaying, which is why the suffix listed was an attribute of the directive. How would you suggest taking in a filter as an attribute? Taking in a name and looking it up with the filterProvider? How would I conditionally filter the bound value?